# How many unspent transaction outputs are there?

Tags: utxo-set

I was wondering the other day how many unspent transaction outputs there are ?

If you just keep track of the unspent transaction outputs you could import private keys, know its balance  and perform spends. How much data is this compared to the full blockchain ?

The biggest downside is that you would not have the full transaction list for a private key/address - just the transactions that you can use for future transaction inputs.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of block 177778 (Apr 29, 2012 6:17:33 PM):

- 2944702 transactions
- 6904591 transaction outputs
- 5376092 transaction inputs
- 1528499 unredeemed outputs left
- 642432 addresses with non-zero balance

Comment: Looking at the number of addresses with nonzero balance, an index versus 'list of blocks address has an unspent tx output in' I calculate would be less than 28 MB. It would then be quick to get the blocks from bitcoind and hence the key's transactions.

Comment: Would a script that reports these numbers be available anywhere?

Comment: I calculated it using a patch for bitcoind that scans the blockchain  at startup, not very user-friendly :)

Comment: A less time-specific answer to the question "How many unspent transaction outputs are there?" would be appreciated.

Comment: @StevenRoose The number isn't fixed, so an answer would have to be "time-specific."

Comment: Where/how did you obtain this info?

Comment: @Geremia [This](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/35987/4334) shows how.