# How big is the UTXO database?

Tags: utxo

Is there a query that will return the size of the UTXO database? Specifically, the total number of unspent outputs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bitcoin Core provides the [`gettxoutsetinfo` RPC](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/gettxoutsetinfo.html) that has exactly the information you want.  Note, it takes that call up to a minute or two to run (and maybe longer as the UTXO set keeps growing).

Here's what my node says right now:

```json
{
  "height": 763253,
  "txouts": 84683939,
  "bogosize": 6314836827,
  "total_amount": 19207623.41689598,
  "transactions": 50344458,
  "disk_size": 5185703215
}
```

Current and historical data may be found on Statoshi.info's [UTXO page](https://statoshi.info/d/000000009/unspent-transaction-output-set).

Comment: It seems to me that having more than one sample output does not benefit the answer, as it will eventually be outdated inevitably. I'd probably roll back to your initial answer, or replace the old output with the current. Although, it is somewhat interesting to see that within half a year the number of txouts has almost doubled.

Comment: @Murch The number of outputs has just about doubled now, to 33409889.

Comment: Does all the nodes store UTXO database? @Murch♦

Comment: @Alper: Yes, all full nodes have the complete UTXO Set.